# ApkSigner fails to sign APK after AGP update to 4.1.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dynatrace, apksigner, apk-signing

I'm using Dynatrace Android Agent. As part of instrumentation it needs to sign the .apk using ApkSigner.jar.
After I updated the Android Gradle Plugin from 4.0.1 to 4.1.0 the signature process has started failing with the following exception:

```
line 134: 51916 Segmentation fault: 11  "${TOOLS_OS}/zipalign" -p -f 4 
"${INSTRUMENTED_APK}" "${ZIPALIGNED_APK}"
Zipaligning completed - Instrumented and zipaligned APK: 
dynatrace/../app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release/dist/app- 
release-zipaligned.apk
Signing non-release APK ...

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to deduce Min API Level from APK's AndroidManifest.xml. Use --min-sdk-version to override.
    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.sign(ApkSignerTool.java:215)
    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.main(ApkSignerTool.java:93)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.getMinSdkVersionFromAndroidManifest(ApkSignerTool.java:779)
    at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.sign(ApkSignerTool.java:213)
    ... 1 more
```

Issue is gone immediately after rolling back the AGP version.

What's causing the signing to fail? How can I fix it without using `--min-sdk-version` param?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very simular to this [question](https://answers.dynatrace.com/spaces/148/uem-open-q-a_2/questions/250045/apksigner-fails-to-sign-apk-after-upgrading-androi.html) on Dynatrace forum.
Please check prerequasites and follow this [quide](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/doc/appmon/user-experience-management/mobile-uem/how-to-instrument-an-android-app/update-to-8/) to migrate to Dynatrace Android Gradle plugin version 8.x